# Problem implementing function with input as string in octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to implement a function astronomical_constants but its giving me error

> 'name' undefined near line 2 column 10

```
function val = astronomical_constants(name)
  switch name
   case 'gravitational_constant'
    val.name = 'gravitational_constant';
    val.value = 6.667e-11;
    val.uncertainity = 1e-12;
   case 'equitorial_radius_earth'
    val.name = 'equitorial_radius_earth';
    val.value = 6*10^(20);
    val.uncertainty = 1e-12;
    endswitch
endfunction

a = astronomical_constants('gravitational_constant').value
```

I'm not able to understand how I can implement it correctly. Pls help

Comment: I guess, you try to run the whole code as a script. Put all the code from `function` to `endfunction` into a proper function file called `astronomical_constants.m`. Then, you're able to call `a = astronomical_constants('gravitational_constant').value` in some script or the command line.

Comment: You can also leave the function in the script, but put e.g. `1;` at the top. See the [docs](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Script-Files.html#Script-Files).

Comment: I have copied your code and cannot reproduce the problem. Even if I copy paste above as is (as my colleagues above suggest), the error is different. Perhaps something else is going on here that you haven't described? How are you trying to run this?